# How to create a server to store results of experiment (Amazon Mechanical Turk)

Tags: mechanicalturk

Please bear with me, I don't know that I have the vocabulary to describe the problem that I am having.

I have written code for an experiment to be implemented in Amazon Mechanical Turk, but it will not save my data for experiments larger than 120 trials. I was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem and how they fixed it. One suggestion would be to have the results of the data be sent to an independent server. What does this mean, and how do I make it happen?

Comment: This question is too broad to really be answered here. To help, you will have to provide considerably more information. In what language are you writing code? Where is the HIT to be hosted (on MTurk, on your own server, etc.)? Are you using someone else's code and that's why it is limited? Please provide more information.

Comment: It would help if you clarify what issue you're running into when you say "[Mechanical Turk]...will not save my data for experiments larger than 120 trials" since that might surface other options.

In the interim, here's one way to address what you're after. Use an External Question and host your own form for input. If you want to capture the results directly, check out this article.